# Date range search using .where on instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model (called Runs), here a 2 instances of it to show what it looks like:

```
<Run id: 138, route_id: 1, leave_date: "2018-07-17 08:00:00", left: false, returned: false, created_at: "2018-07-17 14:08:28", updated_at: "2018-07-17 14:08:28", distance: nil, transport_time: nil>
<Run id: 139, route_id: 1, leave_date: "2018-07-18 09:00:00", left: false, returned: false, created_at: "2018-07-17 14:08:28", updated_at: "2018-07-17 14:08:28", distance: nil, transport_time: nil>
```

There is an instance method on the Run model (in run.rb)

```
  def delivery_date
    (route.delivery_working_day_offset.to_i).business_days.after(leave_date)
  end
```

which provides a datetime e.g:

```
Run.first.delivery_date
```

returns

```
Tue, 17 Jul 2018 09:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

I want to select Runs where the date matches a certain date, using a .where if possible.  Usually I would use something like the following, but it only works on attributes of the model (such as leave_date), but not instance methods (such as delivery_date):

```
Run.where('delivery_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day)
```

How can I perform this selection?
Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: why not persist this attribute as column in your database and then query on it? You can only query on sql columns using ActiveRecord, not on computed values.

Comment: This is a totally a side note to your question, but I would suggest using column names like `leaves_at` instead of `leave_date`. Column names ending `_at` are, by convention, `datetime` fields, whereas columns ending `_on` are, by conention, `date` fields. Your `leave_date` column is actually a `datetime`, which is therefore a confusing name. If it *was* a `date` field, I would call it `leaves_on`.

Comment: Similarly, you could have a new column: `delivery_at`, which is computed **and persisted** when the record is saved. You could then perform the above query in SQL, exactly how you normally would.

Comment: The only thing you need to be careful of, though, is if e.g. the `route.delivery_working_day_offset` can ever change -- in which case, you'd need to recalculate the `delivery_at` on all associated `runs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select method:

```
Run.all.select { |r| r.delivery_date.in?(date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day) }
```

But its not very efficient if you have lots of runs.

I suggest to save delivery date data in table column called `delivery_date` and filter records on db side:

```
Run.where(delivery_date: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Run.all.select { |r| (date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day).include?(r.delivery_date) }
```

Comment: As mentioned above, note that this does not perform the query in SQL - and therefore does not scale; the performance will be terrible if the `runs` table grows large.

Answer (score 0):

There are no chances to call a ruby method from a database query. Also, that has not any reason, because look same as ruby iteration. But you can write a simple similar function in a database query to your ruby method.
Try something like this:

```
Run.joins(:routes)
   .where("runs.leave_date + interval '1 day' * routes.delivery_working_day_offset BETWEEN ? AND ?', 
          date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day)
```

That example ignores the difference between weekend and business days. But there are too many examples of how to write business_days function in a database query.

Easiest solution: save the delivery date to one of databases tables.